# Common pipeline with jenkins-shared-libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm keeping the `Jenkinsfile` on my repositories "lean":

```
@Library('utils') _
def svcName = currentBuild.rawBuild.project.parent.displayName
def sharedLibrary = new pythonApps()

def buildCommands = [ compileData: "python compile.py" ]


timestamps {
    commonPipeline(sharedLibrary, svcName, buildCommands)
}
```

The `commonPipeline.groovy` is inside the shared library under `vars/`. Here it is (truncated):

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def call(sharedLibrary, svcName, buildCommands) {
    pipeline {
        agent { ... }
        stages {
            stage('Compilation') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sharedLibrary.executeStage("compile", buildCommands['compileData'])
                    }
                }
            }
            ... other stages ...
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to allow multiple teams with multiple purposes to use the same pipeline, but with a different `sharedLibrary`.

The issue arises when I need certain jobs to have parameters passed.
I tried adding the parameters section inside the `executeStage` of the shared-library, but as per: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters parameters can be only inside `pipeline` or `stage` block, where in `executeStage` I'm in `steps` block.

Anyhow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the ability. I can add inside `executeStage` this:

```
def executeStage(...) {
    properties([
        parameters([
            booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'test')
        ])
    ])
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The parameters need to be defined before the pipeline starts running. E.g. a label on which to run the pipeline can come in the parameters, so it needs to be defined before the agent is selected, not after it's allocated.

As a side note, the functionality of having "same same but different" build instructions is usually achieved by having different pipelines with the same shared library, not vice versa. The goal of keeping Jenkinsfile extremely short probably wasn't on the designers' radar. With that, if you definitely object to having the pipeline defined in Jenkinsfile, you may try having parameters in the different branches of your library.

Comment: Not helpful at all since it's achievable.